# Converting function to promise alters value of seemingly unrelated variable

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm currently completing a coding challenge and decided that I wanted more practice with promises, so I converted my functions into promises. This went fine for the first one, but when I add a second promise I found something I hadn't expected. This code:

```
// standard code provided for coding challenge
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('ascii');

var input_stdin = "";
var input_stdin_array = "";
var input_currentline = 0;

process.stdin.on('data', function (data) {
    input_stdin += data;
});

process.stdin.on('end', function () {
    input_stdin_array = input_stdin.split("\n");
    main();    
});

function readLine() {
    return input_stdin_array[input_currentline++];
}

function main() {
    var arr = [];
    for(arr_i = 0; arr_i < 6; arr_i++){
       arr[arr_i] = readLine().split(' ');
       arr[arr_i] = arr[arr_i].map(Number);
    }
    // My code
    let x = 0,
        y = 0,
        temp = 0,
        answer = 0;

    /* let incrementXY = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if(x < arr[0].length - 2) {
        x += 1;
      } else {
        y += 1;
        x = 0;
      }
      setTimeout(function(){
        resolve(console.log("x is: " + x + " and y is: " + y));
      }, 250);
    });*/

    // function returns total of each hourglass shape
    let getHourGlass = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      for(j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
        if(j === 0) {
          temp = arr[y][x]; 
        } else {
          temp += arr[y][x + j];
        }
        if(j === 1) {
          temp += arr[y + 1][x + 1];
        }
        temp += arr[y + 2][x + j];
      }
      setTimeout(function(){
        resolve(temp);
      }, 250);
    });

    getHourGlass.then(() => {   
      console.log("Temp is " + temp);
    });
```

Logs out the expected value of 7 for the temp variable.

However, when I uncomment the `incrementXY` promise code, even if I don't implement it at all, suddenly the value logged for `temp` changes from 7 to 4. Given the function does not even reference the temp variable, how can this be? Also, when I convert `incrementXY` into a function, this does not occur, only when it's created as a promise.

If it's useful at all, the current input is a 2D array with this data:

```
1 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 2 4 4 0
0 0 0 2 0 0
0 0 1 2 4 0
```

The other thing I should explain is I'm using the HackerRank sandbox, so it's possible it might be some quirk of their environment, but my hunch tells me it's probably something else.

I could just convert all the code from promises, but I'm thinking this must be some sort of quirk of using promises and would be very grateful if someone could explain to me what's happening so I can feel more confident and able to use them properly in future without odd things happening.

Comment: "Given the function does not even reference the temp variable," but it does mutate `x` and `y` vars and `temp` depends on those vars.

Comment: Ah, I see, it's an encapsulation issue. I shouldn't be using global variables the way I am. Makes sense now, though I wouldn't have though the promise would alter these before it's even called...? Shouldn't it wait until it's called somewhere to start altering values, or is that not how promises work?

Comment: "I'm not calling it" you are calling it when creating a promise. Promise constructor will synchronously execute the function you have passed into it `var promise = new Promise(resolve => {
  console.log('Promise creation')
  setTimeout(resolve, 1000)
})

console.log('Next synchronous line')
promise.then( () => console.log('Promise resolved'))`

Comment: Oh, I see, when the promise is assigned to a variable it will start performing operations on any variables etc, is that correct? So it wasn't doing that when I was  creating `incrementXY` as a function because I wasn't assigning it to a variable? Part of my reasoning for creating promises was so things *weren't* messing with variables before getHourGlass had returned its value for temp.

Comment: Wait. It seems you have some wrong ideas about what promises are. They are not interchangeable with functions. They are not callable, they don't have notion of performing something. It's just a value that will be available sometime later. When you call `new Promise(fn)` promise constructor will execute `fn` with `resolve` and `reject` callbacks. If your `fn` does some side-effects in the moment of call or later say using `setTimeout` it has nothing to do w/ the promise itself and weather you assigned it to a variable or not.

Comment: I don't want to turn this into an extended discussion, but am I right in saying that at the time a promise is created with `var foo = new Promise(...)` etc, any side-effects will occur at that point and in this regard they are different from functions, which will only have side-effects when explicitly called, even after being assigned to a variable? Or is this an over-simplification?

Comment: Promises and Functions are hardly comparable in this way. It is a function you are passing into `Promise` constructor that has (or hasn't) side effects. `var foo = new Promise(fn)` could be rewritten `var fn = function(resolve){...}, foo = new Promise(fn)`. As you can see any effects of `fn` are totally unrelated to promises. So it is up to `fn` implementation when and how effects occur.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko You should put those comments together in an answer.

Comment: @Bergi I'd certainly be glad to see it all working on a practical level, and would of course accept an answer that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this part

> However, when I uncomment the `incrementXY` promise code, even if I don't implement it at all, suddenly the value logged for `temp` changes from 7 to 4. Given the function does not even reference the `temp` variable, how can this be?

Variable `temp` depends on defined in the same scope `x` and `y`. Executor function that you pass to `Promise` constructor changes those variables affecting the value of `temp`.

```js
let a = 0

const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
  console.log(`Creating a promise: ${a}`)
  a++
  
  setTimeout(resolve, 1000)
})

console.log(`Promise created: ${a}`)
a++
promise.then(() => console.log(`Promise resolved: ${a}`))
```

So your problem was not with promises per se but with shared mutable state.

> so I converted my functions into promises

This doesn't make much sense. First of all, I don't see why your code needs Promises at all. It all looks like you have all values available by the time you are running this code.

Then Promises and Functions are not interchangeable. One can consider Promise to be a *value* that will be available sometime later. It has no notion of action or operation. It is executor function you are passing into promise constructor that does all the dirty job.

But if you want to play with promises you could do something like this

```js
const delay = fn => timeout =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(fn()), timeout))

/* do not use shared mutable state 
let x = 0,
  y = 1,
  temp = 0;
  */
  

// promises are values (not functions)
const calculatingXY = delay(() => ({x: 1, y: 2}))(250)

calculatingXY.then(({x, y}) => console.log(`Value of x is ${x}, value of y is ${y}`))

// sum x and y after 500 ms timeout
const calculatingSum = calculatingXY
  .then(
    ({x, y}) => delay(() => x + y)(500)
  )

Promise.all([calculatingXY, calculatingSum])
  .then(
    ([{x,y}, z]) => console.log(`${x} + ${y} = ${z}`)
  )
  .catch(e => console.log(e))
```